# GUI Development for Audio Software development?

Tags: user-interface, programming-languages, audio

I am new to GUI programming and I would like some suggestions with how to get started with this subject. I need to develop GUI parts for software prototypes and interfaces for software products.

I currently have a Windows computer running Win 7 and I have Visual Studio 2008 and 2010. I would truly appreciate any help on to what software tools (frameworks, IDE's, programming languages,etc) I could pickup to get the job done and be able to proficiently create good applications.

I have experience in C++ and some java, however I am completely open to learning any other language if its the best choice for what I want to accomplish. Thank you very much in advance.

Sergio

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Any preferences with audio / GUI libraries or frameworks, what language will these prototypes be written in? I presume you don't want to develop everything from scratch hooking to OS audio driver and blotting pixels on the screen through graphics card driver? :)

Comment: So far I don't have preferences on GUI libraries or frameworks as I haven't had experience in GUI development. The prototypes will be audio processing algorithms written mainly in C/C++. Definitely don't want to start from scratch if possible!

Comment: What I want to achieve eventually is to have an interface to use these audio algorithms and proprietary technology from the company.

Answer (score 1):

for cross platform app production, Nokia Qt Toolkit is the best option. For windows only, Visual Studio has a builtin [Windows Forms Designer](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9d/Visual_Studio_2010_WinForms_Designer.png) or you could use the [WPF Designer](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/48/Visual_Studio_2010_WPF_Designer_View.png) for GUI. Do you need audio libraries as well (your question is unclear)?

Comment: No, no audio libraries at the moment, just need to create the interface(s) to use already written algorithms.

Comment: is your interface targeted towards multiple platforms (windows, linux, mac)?

Comment: yes. It will start with just windows but it needs to be targeted towards other platforms as well.

Comment: then Qt is the best option if you want to code once and deploy (compile) on every platform. Download the Qt SDK and start with the official book http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0132354160 - it is availible free with code examples

Answer (score 1):

Try [JUCE](http://www.juce.com/about-juce), it designed for this stuff.